# javascript: object that contains the customers that belong to each bank

Tags: javascript, aem-6

through es6, the exercise consists in showing objects in which the keys are the names of the banks and the values ​​in a disposition with the textnumber of their clients.

with the following matrices

```
 const clients = [
{ id: 1, taxNumber: '86620855', name: 'HECTOR ACUÑA BOLAÑOS'},
{ id: 2, taxNumber: '7317855K', name: 'JESUS RODRIGUEZ ALVAREZ'},
{ id: 3, taxNumber: '73826497', name: 'ANDRES NADAL MOLINA'},
{ id: 4, taxNumber: '88587715', name: 'SALVADOR ARNEDO MANRIQUEZ'},
{ id: 5, taxNumber: '94020190', name: 'VICTOR MANUEL ROJAS LUCAS'},
{ id: 6, taxNumber: '99804238', name: 'MOHAMED FERRE SAMPER' }
];
const accounts = [
{ clientId: 6, bankId: 1, balance: 15000 },
{ clientId: 1, bankId: 3, balance: 18000 },
{ clientId: 5, bankId: 3, balance: 135000 },
{ clientId: 2, bankId: 2, balance: 5600 },
{ clientId: 3, bankId: 1, balance: 23000 },
{ clientId: 5, bankId: 2, balance: 15000 },
{ clientId: 3, bankId: 3, balance: 45900 },
{ clientId: 2, bankId: 3, balance: 19000 },
{ clientId: 4, bankId: 3, balance: 51000 },
{ clientId: 5, bankId: 1, balance: 89000 },
{ clientId: 1, bankId: 2, balance: 1600 },
{ clientId: 5, bankId: 3, balance: 37500 },
{ clientId: 6, bankId: 1, balance: 19200 },
{ clientId: 2, bankId: 3, balance: 10000 },
{ clientId: 3, bankId: 2, balance: 5400 },
{ clientId: 3, bankId: 1, balance: 9000 },
{ clientId: 4, bankId: 3, balance: 13500 },
{ clientId: 2, bankId: 1, balance: 38200 },
{ clientId: 5, bankId: 2, balance: 17000 },
{ clientId: 1, bankId: 3, balance: 1000 },
{ clientId: 5, bankId: 2, balance: 600 },
{ clientId: 6, bankId: 1, balance: 16200 },
{ clientId: 2, bankId: 2, balance: 10000 }

]
const banks = [
{ id: 1, name: 'BankA' },
{ id: 2, name: 'BankB' },
{ id: 3, name: 'BankC' }
];
```

then the result would be something like this:

```
0: {bank: 'BankA', clients: {'99804238', '94020190', '73826497'} } ,
1: {bank: 'BankB', clients: {'7317855K', '94020190', '86620855'} } ,
2: {bank: 'BankC', clients: {'73826497', '86620855', '88587715'} }
```

Basically, this result contains the name of the bank that contains a 
   client value, which contains all the text numbers of the clients that 
   use that bank.

the final result would contain the total number of clients of each bank, 
  only reference image.

```
function banksClientsTaxNumbers() {

var map = accounts.reduce(function(map, acc) {

    var bankByid = acc.bankId
    map[bankByid ] = {} 

    return map 
  }, {})

  console.log(map)

  var array = Object.keys(map).map(function(id) {

    var bank = banks.find(function(bank) {
        return bank.id == id;

    })

    var account = accounts.filter(function(account) {
        return account.bankId == id;

    })
    console.log(account)

    return {
      banco: bank.name,
      clients: account
    }
  });
  console.log(array)
```

}

The result of this code is:

[image result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jxOHV.png)

As you can see, the accounts that each bank contains are listed, but we still have to reach the array of clients to show them by textnumber, help please!

If you achieve the logic of this exercise, I thank you in advance. Regards!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To reduce time complexity, turn the `clients` into an object of `taxNumber`s indexed by client ID, and do the same for the `banks`, indexed by bank ID. Then you can `reduce` the `accounts` into an accumulator indexed by `bankId`, add each client to a `Set` (to deduplicate), then transform the `Set` into an array, `O(N)`:

```js
const clients=[{id:1,taxNumber:'86620855',name:'HECTOR ACUÑA BOLAÑOS'},{id:2,taxNumber:'7317855K',name:'JESUS RODRIGUEZ ALVAREZ'},{id:3,taxNumber:'73826497',name:'ANDRES NADAL MOLINA'},{id:4,taxNumber:'88587715',name:'SALVADOR ARNEDO MANRIQUEZ'},{id:5,taxNumber:'94020190',name:'VICTOR MANUEL ROJAS LUCAS'},{id:6,taxNumber:'99804238',name:'MOHAMED FERRE SAMPER'}];const accounts=[{clientId:6,bankId:1,balance:15000},{clientId:1,bankId:3,balance:18000},{clientId:5,bankId:3,balance:135000},{clientId:2,bankId:2,balance:5600},{clientId:3,bankId:1,balance:23000},{clientId:5,bankId:2,balance:15000},{clientId:3,bankId:3,balance:45900},{clientId:2,bankId:3,balance:19000},{clientId:4,bankId:3,balance:51000},{clientId:5,bankId:1,balance:89000},{clientId:1,bankId:2,balance:1600},{clientId:5,bankId:3,balance:37500},{clientId:6,bankId:1,balance:19200},{clientId:2,bankId:3,balance:10000},{clientId:3,bankId:2,balance:5400},{clientId:3,bankId:1,balance:9000},{clientId:4,bankId:3,balance:13500},{clientId:2,bankId:1,balance:38200},{clientId:5,bankId:2,balance:17000},{clientId:1,bankId:3,balance:1000},{clientId:5,bankId:2,balance:600},{clientId:6,bankId:1,balance:16200},{clientId:2,bankId:2,balance:10000}]
const banks=[{id:1,name:'BankA'},{id:2,name:'BankB'},{id:3,name:'BankC'}]



const taxNumberByClientId = clients.reduce(
  (a, { id, taxNumber }) => Object.assign(a, { [id]: taxNumber }),
  {}
);
const banksByBankId = banks.reduce(
  (a, { id, name }) => Object.assign(a, { [id]: name }),
  {}
);

const taxNumbersByBank = accounts.reduce((a, { clientId, bankId }) => {
  const bankName = banksByBankId[bankId];
  const taxNumber = taxNumberByClientId[clientId];
  if (!a[bankName]) a[bankName] = new Set();
  a[bankName].add(taxNumber);
  return a;
}, {});
const results = Object.entries(taxNumbersByBank)
  .map(([bank, clientsSet]) => ({
    bank,
    clients: [...clientsSet]
  }));
console.log(results);
```

Comment: it is right! You have made me see another perspective, thank you very much! : D, then it is necessary to convert the array into objects and index by id, this is something that did not.

Comment: It is not *necessary*, but it definitely reduces time complexity compared to, for example, nested `.find`s.

Answer (score 0):

It can be further simplified as follows:

```js
const clients = [
  { id: 1, taxNumber: '86620855', name: 'HECTOR ACUÑA BOLAÑOS' },
  { id: 2, taxNumber: '7317855K', name: 'JESUS RODRIGUEZ ALVAREZ' },
  { id: 3, taxNumber: '73826497', name: 'ANDRES NADAL MOLINA' },
  { id: 4, taxNumber: '88587715', name: 'SALVADOR ARNEDO MANRIQUEZ' },
  { id: 5, taxNumber: '94020190', name: 'VICTOR MANUEL ROJAS LUCAS' },
  { id: 6, taxNumber: '99804238', name: 'MOHAMED FERRE SAMPER' }
];
const accounts = [
  { clientId: 6, bankId: 1, balance: 15000 },
  { clientId: 1, bankId: 3, balance: 18000 },
  { clientId: 5, bankId: 3, balance: 135000 },
  { clientId: 2, bankId: 2, balance: 5600 },
  { clientId: 3, bankId: 1, balance: 23000 },
  { clientId: 5, bankId: 2, balance: 15000 },
  { clientId: 3, bankId: 3, balance: 45900 },
  { clientId: 2, bankId: 3, balance: 19000 },
  { clientId: 4, bankId: 3, balance: 51000 },
  { clientId: 5, bankId: 1, balance: 89000 },
  { clientId: 1, bankId: 2, balance: 1600 },
  { clientId: 5, bankId: 3, balance: 37500 },
  { clientId: 6, bankId: 1, balance: 19200 },
  { clientId: 2, bankId: 3, balance: 10000 },
  { clientId: 3, bankId: 2, balance: 5400 },
  { clientId: 3, bankId: 1, balance: 9000 },
  { clientId: 4, bankId: 3, balance: 13500 },
  { clientId: 2, bankId: 1, balance: 38200 },
  { clientId: 5, bankId: 2, balance: 17000 },
  { clientId: 1, bankId: 3, balance: 1000 },
  { clientId: 5, bankId: 2, balance: 600 },
  { clientId: 6, bankId: 1, balance: 16200 },
  { clientId: 2, bankId: 2, balance: 10000 }

]
const banks = [
  { id: 1, name: 'BankA' },
  { id: 2, name: 'BankB' },
  { id: 3, name: 'BankC' }
];

function banksClientsTaxNumbers() {
  return banks.reduce((obj, bank) => {
    return {
      ...obj,
      [bank.name]: accounts
        .filter(account => account.bankId === bank.id)
        .map(account => account.clientId)
        .filter((value, index, array) => array.indexOf(value) === index)
        .map(clientId => clients.find(client => client.id === clientId))
        .sort(function (a, b) { return a.name.toLowerCase().localeCompare(b.name.toLowerCase()); })
        .map(client => client.taxNumber)
    }
  }, {})
}



console.log(banksClientsTaxNumbers());
```

Comment: first of all welcome to stackoverfllow,please read through https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask how to ask question and provide more details on your problem for better understanding for community to answer your question.